# Async over Task.WhenAll() does not work in Unit Test

Tags: asp.net-core, async-await

I'm unit testing some async MVC .netcore code that is working when it's running, but hitting an ObjectDisposedexception during unit testing.
Background: I have another method similar to this one that performs a single async action, returns a task, and also works while running AND when I unit test it like this.
So far no matter how I refactor this I'm getting: 'Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'System.Net.Http.StreamContent'' when trying to unit test.

The method:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Foo>> GetFoos() {
var idList = GetFooIds();
var tasks = Enumerable.Range(0, idList.Count)
                  .Select(i => GetFooById(idList[i]));

var fooResults = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

var foos = new HashSet<Foo>();
foos.UnionWith(fooResults.SelectMany(x => x));

return foos;
}
```

The unit test approach that works w/ the single Async task, but not here:

```
[TestMethod]
public void CanGetFoos() {
    ...
    var result = service.GetFoos().Result;
    Assert.AreEqual(2, result.Count());
}
```

And I doubt the inner method is a factor, but here it is:

```
private async Task<List<Foo>> GetFooById(string id)
{
    var nextPageExists = true;
    var fooList = new List<Foo>();
    var pageNumber = 1;
    while (nextPageExists)
    using (var response =
        await Client.GetAsync(GetFooUri(id, pageNumber++))
    {
        var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        var fooResponse =
            JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Foo>(content);
        fooList.AddRange(fooResponse.Objects);
        if (!Convert.ToBoolean(fooList.More))
            nextPageExists = false;
    })

    return fooList;
}
```

Comment: Please post a [minimal, complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The only odd thing I see is the use of `Result`, which isn't necessary (MSTest supports `async Task` unit tests), but also wouldn't cause this error.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look @StephenCleary.  I did of course try changing the test itself to aysnc...same result as you expect.  Which bits of the solution do you suppose I should add to the example?  There is no code in the service constructor (just DI mapping)...maybe the rest of the test method?

Comment: Start with the complete code and then keep removing parts of it until the problem stops. Then add back in the last part and remove other parts of it. Repeat until there is nothing left you can remove, and you should have something small enough to post.